# Apache Pig: Syntax error with 'DUMP' in macro definition

Tags: java, macros, apache-pig

I encountered an interesting problem with macro definition in pig. Here's the code:

```
DEFINE Func(src) RETURNS dst{
  $dst = GROUP $src ALL;
  DUMP $dst;
}
raw = LOAD 'data';
grp = Func(raw);
```

And when execute those codes in grunt shell, there will be an error:

```
ERROR 1200:... Failed to parse macro 'Func'. Reason:... Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'DUMP'
```

But, where did I make the mistake? O.O

Answer (score 1):

I found that someone has already reported the bug(if we call that a bug: [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3910)) a long time ago, but it seems the Pig developing team is not planing to solve that. :(